# Docusign: Create template to display dynamic list of text

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking for a way to build a table in a docusign template where the rows could be bound dynamically using the input data. For example, in the sample below the "Selected Options" is the table and the rows are dynamic user inputs :

```
**Selected Options**
2 bedroom
lake facing
non-smoking
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Ergin says, DocuSign doesn't support *dynamic* creation of tables in a Document, such that the length (size) of the table will automatically vary according to how much data (i.e., how many rows) are specified. Your **Create Envelope** request specifies a (static) document, and you use DocuSign tabs to overlay data on top of that static document in specific locations.

That said, few options you might consider:

- Create the table in your (static) document to contain the maximum number of columns/rows that it could ever possibly contain. Then, place tabs in every cell -- but in the **Create Envelope** request, only populate the tabs that correspond to the data the user provides.  The down side of this approach would be that you could end up with a table that has several blank/empty rows, if the user doesn't specify much data.

OR

- A more complex approach would be ***not*** define the Document in the Template itself, but rather, have the **Create Envelope** API request dynamically specify the Document, based on how much data the user provides. For example, if the table could contain between 1-3 rows, you could create 3 static documents -- the first with a one-row table, the second with a 2-row table, and the third with a 3-row table.  Then, include logic in your code to determine how much data the user provides (1 row, 2 rows, or 3 rows), and specify the appropriate Document in the **Create Envelope** request.  (Hint: you'd need to use 'Composite Templates' structure in the API request to accomplish this -- there's lots of info about that here on StackOverflow.)  Biggest upside of this approach would be that the table in the document would always be the right size to exactly accommodate the user-provided data -- but obviously this approach could be challenging to implement and maintain if your document contains multiple tables and/or a large number of max potential rows in each table.

OR

- Finally, in the same spirit as option #2 above -- if there's just a small number of variations of table size (for example: the table will always contain 1, 2, or 3 rows), you could simply create 3 Templates via the DocuSign web UI -- the first Template containing a Document with a one-row table, the second Template containing a Document with a 2-row table, and the third Template containing a Document with a 3-row table.  Then, include logic in your code to dynamically choose the right template to use in the **Create Envelope** request, based upon how much data the user provides (1 row, 2 rows, or 3 rows).

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not support generic "tables" in the documents, so if you want to use a table it will have to be created at the document layer then uploaded into DocuSign.

One possible option is to create a the layout for a table in your document and leave spaces where the data will eventually go, then read or otherwise designate those locations on the document where the fields are, then finally you can place DocuSign tabs at those locations and that would in turn populate your table.